# Web2py Basic Auth - Authenticated User Info

Tags: web2py

I am using Basic Auth in Web2p. Usually i would use auth.user from within the function to get information related to the authenticated user, this does not seem to work when i am authenticated by Basic Authentication. 
Is there something i am missing?

Here Is my auth settings

```
auth.settings.remember_me_form=False
auth.settings.password_min_length = 8
auth.settings.registration_requires_verification = True
auth.settings.registration_requires_approval = False
auth.settings.reset_password_requires_verification = True
```

The function i am using to test

```
def call():
    session.forget()
    return service()

auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
@auth.requires_login()
@service.run
def test():
    a = auth.user
    b= 'hello'
    return(a,b)
```

The purpose of this is to get the profile details of the authenticated user via a HTTP request for a phonegap app. i am using

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('email', 'passwd'))
```

it Authenticates but returns none for auth.user

Thanks

Comment: Can you show some code? How have you set up Auth? What information are you trying to get, and where?

Comment: Anthony, I added more information to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/10/services#Services-and-Authentication), you should not use the Auth decorators on RPC functions. Instead, you should decorate the `call()` function:

```
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
@auth.requires_login()
def call():
    session.forget()
    return service()

@service.run
def test():
    a = auth.user
    b = 'hello'
    return (a, b)
```

Anyway, you might not be satisfied with the format of the response when using the above method, as the "run" service simply applies `str()` to the return value -- so, you get something like:

```
"(<Row {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'email': 'john@doe.com', 'id': '1L'}>, 'hello')"
```

A simpler approach would just be to return JSON:

```
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True
@auth.requires_login()
def test():
    from gluon.serializers import json
    return json((auth.user, 'hello'))
```

Then request:

```
r = requests.get('http://yourdomain.com/yourapp/default/test',
                 auth=HTTPBasicAuth('email', 'passwd'))
```

In that case, there is no need to use `service()` or to create a `call()` function.

Comment: seems like the way i had it , i was never actually asking for authentication. If i set it up correctly as in your examples i can not authenticate i just get 403. 
i have tried putting the auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True in db.py and the controller but neither work am i missing something?

Comment: No, you had the `@auth.requires_login()` decorator on the `test()` function, but it belongs on the `call()` function (as shown above). In your case, the problem was that login/authentication was not happening at all, as the `requires_login` restriction was not actually being applied -- so you would get a response even if passing bad credentials. If the above is still not working, it is probably because you are not sending the credentials of a registered user (you must first register the user so there is an associated record in the `auth_user` table).

Comment: I created a new user account and it authenticated with your example. Seems that there was a problem with my old user account stopping it working with your example but allowing it to login via a browser.
Thank you for the help.